# Is there any way to get this segmented retention data via YT API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, retention, youtube-analytics

I'm trying to calculate the absolute audience retention per each 20 seconds of my yt video (on my channel).

It should be:

```
(#views till now) / (#total views)
```

I called the YT analytics API, but I only see "views" metric per the whole video.

Is there any way to get this segmented retention data via API?

The API returns "views" per the whole video (or segmented by day):

[image: https://screenshot.googleplex.com/5nYQX4aw7rTsQfH]

Nothing else under "audience retention":
[image]